# Facebook PHP SDK - Regardless Of Whether User Clicks 'Allow' or 'Don't Allow' They Are Still Taken To The App Canvas Page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

As mentioned in the title, I have an app and when the auth dialogue is shown requesting permissions, regardless of whether the `Allow` or `Don't Allow` button is clicked by the user they are still redirected to the app canvas page.

I understand it's to do with the `redirect_uri` but is there a way to differentiate between the two actions to execute different logic based on the button that is clicked?

```
// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
else {
     $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                              'fbconnect' => 0,
                                              'display' => 'page',
                                              'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.domain.com/facebook/2011/app1/redirect.php&scope=publish_stream',
                                              'req_perms' => 'publish_stream'));
```

`redirect.php` on my domain simply redirects back to the app.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will redirect to the same url regardless of what button is pressed in the auth dialog, but with different GET parameters:

If the user denies your app access, it should put the following params in the url

- error_reason=user_denied
- error=access_denied
- error_description=The+user+denied+your+request

You need to handle this in your redirect page.

```
if(isset($_GET['error']))
{
    die($_GET['error_description']);
}
else
{
    // ... redirect as usual
}
```